# Android log output stream of two devices simultaneously

Tags: android, logcat

I've connected two devices to my pc (one over usb, the other over wlan). In eclipse I can see the output stream of only one of the devices in logcat. Is there a way to log both output streams even if there streaming simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

no ADB logcat doesnt have a device ID argument, so directly you cant view both, however, you can redirect the log output of both device to a common server/system/IP and then view it there

Comment: Ok, you might be right, but im pretty sure you arent, you just have to specify device id with `-s` and it will display logcat of that device

Comment: Right so, even if you are in Linux and concatenate commands using '|' , the system will just switch from one to the other, unless you get 2 instances of ADB running. which surely seems possible on linux, but i'm not sure on Windows

Comment: i have just tried on Linux, no need for 2 instances of adb just 2 terminals, i dont know if it would work in windows or not. here is the screenshot https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21407545/Screenshot.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but not in eclipse:
You can open 2 terminals/cmds than do this

In each of terminals you just type

```
adb -s [device id] logcat
```

where device id is what you get when you type `adb devices`
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thx  that works ! But just one further question: How can I filter the logcat output (per Tag) ??

Comment: You can do it like this: `adb -s [device] logcat -s "TAGNAME". If it worked please mark answer accepted. thanks